# Copy folder from source to target during maven build

Tags: java, maven, build, pom.xml

I have source files and JRE folder inside the source folder. When I do maven build for my source I want complete JRE folder from source to be copied into target folder. But as of now few files in JRE folder skipped copying to target. Due to which JRE in target folder is corrupted. How to specify in pom.xml to copy whole source JRE folder to target folder.

Comment: Why do you have JRE files in your source folder? Does not make sense...Apart from that the copying will be done automatically during the maven build...If the files are being corruppted you might have activated filtering...but without the whole pom file it is hard to say what's wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You can copy any files from arbitrary directories of your project to your target directory with Maven [resources plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/). You only have to specify your source JRE folder as a resource.